# forcing landscape orientation oncreate activity loop

Tags: android, landscape-portrait

I create an android app with many activities i want to make one of them landscape orientation :

```
public class tutorialActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener  {

    private SurfaceView   mSurfaceView;
    private MediaPlayer   mMediaPlayer;
    private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
    private LinearLayout buttonRegister;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tutorial);
        buttonRegister = findViewById(R.id.button_register);
        buttonRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Intent i = new Intent(tutorialActivity.this, MenuActivity.class);
                // startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });

        mSurfaceView = findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
        mSurfaceHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
        mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(tutorialActivity.this);

    }
}
```

and specify into my manifest file :

```
<activity android:name=".activities.tutorialActivity"
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.base"></activity>
```

when i show this activity the oncreate activity loop infinitely please help me on this issue

Answer (score 1):

Manifest:

```
<activity  
    android:name=".YourActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape">
```

Activity:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```